# Как пользоваться pypy в PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pypy

Узнав об иных интерпретаторах, которые ускорят работу программы, я решил воспользоваться одним из них, выбрал *pypy* и проверил на рабочем проекте. После установки и попытки вставить его в виртуальное окружение, пришел к проблеме: не устанавливается модуль *PyQt5*. Распробовав множества способов решения, не пришел ни к чему, возможно, я допустил ошибку раньше (до установки виртуального окружения).

Пожалуйста, расскажите как вы привязывали *pypy* к *PyCharm* или использовали другой интерпретатор для ускорения работы программы.

P.s.: я проверил *pypy* c другим кодом уже без PyQt5, и код работал. Получается pypy я установил верно, но почему не устанавливается *PyQt5* на *pypy*, я не знаю. При этом все остальные модули спокойно устанавливаются.

P.ss: Command output:

```
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.8.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Г— Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  в”‚ exit code: 1
  в•°в”Ђ> [29 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files\pypy3.9-v7.3.11-win64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 144, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files\pypy3.9-v7.3.11-win64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Program Files\pypy3.9-v7.3.11-win64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Program Files\pypy3.9-v7.3.11-win64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 148, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\erofe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5d5o3slq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
        File "C:\Users\erofe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5d5o3slq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "C:\Users\erofe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5d5o3slq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 585, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "project.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\erofe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5d5o3slq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\erofe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5d5o3slq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 236, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\erofe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5d5o3slq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Г— Encountered error while generating package metadata.
в•°в”Ђ> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

И предлагает ввести в терминал

```
pip install PyQt5
```

Установку происходит успешно, но при запуске не работает.

Comment: Определитесь, с чем у вас конкретно проблема — с привязкой pypy к PyCharm или с установкой PyQt5 в pypy? Это две никак не связанные вещи

Comment: Я бы попробовал запустить `pypy -m pip install pyqt5`, чтобы установка шла именно через pypy. А там уже смотреть по ситуации.

Comment: @insolor Я ввел это в терминал и вывело C:\Program Files\pypy3.8-v7.3.11-win64\pypy.exe: No module named pip (to install pip, you need to run once "C:\Program Files\pypy3.8-v7.3.11-win64\pypy.exe -m ensurepip") Я понял что нужно ввести то что в кавычках, но куда не ввожу везде выдает ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь вкладкой Python Packages. В строке поиска вбейте PyQt5.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установите пакет средствами PyCharm. Установка будет произведена в правильное место. Так же этот значок позволяет деинсталлировать пакет или выбрать версию пакета для установки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы пробовали это делать именно на pypy?

Comment: Нет, с pypy вообще ничего не пробовал. Если пользуетесь PyCharm - оптимальным будет именно приведенный мной способ установки. Даже pip может установить пакеты не туда куда нужно, если неверно настроена среда разработки.

Comment: Ну а вопрос именно про pypy, так что ваш ответ по сути не имеет смысла

Comment: Дело ваше. Но я бы не создавал себе лишние сложности.

Comment: Таким образом и устанавливаю все модули, но здесь выдает ошибку при установке PyQt5.